# Custom Post type easy way for editors

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

just started working with Wordpress,and also complete noob about eveything web-related.

I'm trying to create a custom article/post type page coming from a free theme, so i'd like a custom article type with it's own custom attributes and a template for showing it in a particular way. I don't know what is the easiest way to do that. What I aim for is an easy interface for an editor to choose the custom category for the post, fill some fields and publish it, and let the system show it the right way.

I tried with the free plugin Toolset, which let me create a custom page/article type with its own attributes, which correctly shows in the editor when editing articles, but do not let me format it and show it in the page, not without buying the complete version I guess. So now I've got a custom page type but I don't know how to "write" something that tells the site to show that particular type of article in that particular way.

Is there any easy way? As now i'm not familiar with html/css/php (but willful to learn the basics if needed) in any way, and so i was trying to use some easy interface to do that, I tried another plugin, Elementor, but it's oriented to single pages and i'm unable to replicate the layout automatically for a specific type of article, neither to retrieve data from the article dinamically. Note that I do not need extensive customization features, just a simple layout showing an image (setted when editing), and some text fields filled in article creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create your desired custom post types. Since you are not yet familiar with coding, use a plugin from the wordpress directory https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Now that you created your own custom post types, you need to create the templates for each custom post type. This will allow you to have different ways of presenting the articles depending on their type. You can refer to this article from from Wordpress : https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Although this may seem simple while reading, it might be totally messy when it comes to coding your templates especially for you who is not yet very familiar with wordpress. I suggest that you find someone who can help you to at least setup this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you briefly clarify this for me? By modifing the php post type template (for istance by cloning the single post default page from my theme) how could I define the graphical structure and layout of the page? I get that in php I could access data from the post and maybe set some variable, but isn't some html/css to modify as well for defining "where goes this and that"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the last sentence. Cloning or creating a template specifically for a custom post type gives you the total freedom to re-layout and re-style the whole template. It means you have to dive into the code. This is not limited to css/html only but php as well. The graphical structure and layout of the page will be based on how you design that template. Once you saved that, the custom post type will be using that template and will be presented in a way you designed the template.

Comment: All right, I guess I should look to a tutorial for modifing/extending a given single post page from a theme. Thank you.